# css top:xx; difference mac/windows

Tags: html, css

My website looks different on mac than on windows (every browser) so it should not be a browser thing but a Mac/windows problem:

This is my code:

```
height: 359px;
top: 243px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
```

So nothing special, but this is how it looks alright on mac but in windows it looks right when:

```
top: 271px;
```

There are 28px difference,...why?

So how can I target only (all browser) on mac or windows - or is there an other solution?

Comment: Remember to reset your CSS, because browsers apply some default styles (like `margins` or `padding`), and those can cause your layout to appear differently on different browsers. Search for a CSS reset, or you can achieve the most basic functionality by adding this to your CSS: * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Comment: you are probably getting padding/margin from current or parent element

Comment: can u show your completed code and give us exaple ...........